# Can $\sigma_4(n)$ be a square number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Denote $\sigma_k(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d^k,$ then $$\sigma_1(3)=2^2,\sigma_2(42)=50^2,\sigma_3(2)=3^2,$$
 and both $\sigma_1(345)$ and $\sigma_3(345)$ are square numbers:
$$\sigma_1(345)=24^2,\sigma_3(345)=6552^2.$$
**My question:** Can $\sigma_4(n)$ be a square number $(n>1)$? (I checked $n$ from $2$ to $10^6,$ but there is no such $n$.)

Comment: I checked up to $10^8$ ad found none. Perhaps there is some modular argument to exclude solutions.

Comment: Expanding $\sum_{d|n}(2+d)^4$ for an odd integer $n>1$, we obtain $\sigma_4(n)\equiv \sigma_0(n)\mod 4$, thus we exclude two (little) cases studying the parity of $K$ and if $n$ is a perfect square or not. Since $\sigma_4(2^a)=1\mod 4$, by multiply in first conguence we exclude the same cases (for even numbers). Neither are solutions for $K$ even with $t=2^a$, $a\geq 1$, since expanding $\sum_{d|t}(1+d)^4\equiv \sigma_0(t)-1\mod 4$, we obtain  $\sigma_4(t)+\sigma_2(t)=-1\mod 4$.